# capybara get request instead of post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara

all.

I am stuck with Capybara and Rails.
In the view I have a link with method: :post

```
= link_to t(:add_to_cart), offer_add_to_cart_path(offer), class: 'btn', remote: true, method: :post
```

At my work computer (Ubuntu) all specs are passing ok, but at home computer (Mac OS X), get an error

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/offers/1/add_to_cart"
```

When capybara does

```
click_on t(:add_to_cart)
```

rails (4.2.1)
capybara (2.4.4)
capybara-webkit (1.5.0)

Comment: Have you found solution as experiencing the same issue ?

Comment: Nope, those project has died already (